# How to configure asynchronous lambda invocation via API Gateway using SAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I have configured a lambda proxy integration with API Gateway using SAM specification and am invoking the lambda asynchronously by passing X-Amz-Invocation-Type: "'Event'" header

```
  ApiGateway:
      Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
      Properties:
        StageName: prod
        DefinitionBody:
          swagger: "2.0"
          info:
            title:
              Ref: AWS::StackName
            description: API endpoint for invoking LambdaFunction
            version: 1.0.0
          paths:
            /items:
              post:
                consumes: ["application/json"]
                produces: ["application/json"]
                responses: {}
                x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                  type: "aws_proxy"
                  uri:
                    Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${LambdaFunction.Arn}/invocations
                  passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
                  httpMethod: "POST"
                  requestParameters:
                      integration.request.header.X-Amz-Invocation-Type: "'Event'"
```

The problem is that lambda is returning empty response(invoked async) so API Gateway is throwing following error

Wed Nov 14 08:03:14 UTC 2018 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response
Wed Nov 14 08:03:14 UTC 2018 : Method completed with status: 502

Is this behaviour expected? Do I have to define responses explicitly? I do not want to throw 200 always because I also want to send bad request and unauthorized errors as well.What's the solution to avoid this problem?

Comment: Where did you define the lambda? Please add this and relevant code (your node lambda code) to the question.  You have a problem in the code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AWS Api Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-integration-async.html) doesn't allow this.

This has to be unchecked to be very specific when using async integration.
[image]

Plus you don’t need to actually pass the X-Amz-Invocation-Type header in the request.

Async invocation, unfortunately, does not work with the lambda-proxy (aws_proxy) integration type.

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck on the same problem.

you can either modify the manually API-gateway which can break if you forgot any step.

or else create script which modify api-gateway to make lambda function invocation async

I am using aws-sdk js to modify api-gateway programmatically
for reference you can check code [here](https://himanshupatil.dev/programmatically-convert-api-gateway-sync-invoke-lambda-to-async)